# Windows 10 Search can't find my local files

Tags: windows, search, cortana

This is what happends when I try to find some local file for example a mp3 file:

Searching "X" mp3 file:

[image]

This are my indexing options:

Indexing options:

[image]

Comment: Click advanced for more indexing options.